# 8 extra bytes in stack

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

i am new to buffer overflow and learning from securitytube.net website but in 7th video i got stucked [Buffer Overflow Primer Part 7 (Exploiting A Program Demo)](http://www.securitytube.net/video/251)

In this when the value of egg is passed through the vulnerable program on one point 80 bytes are loaded on the stack but mine computer is loading 88 bytes due to which i am not able to smash the stack.

I have faced the same problem with the shellcoder's handbook second edition page 33 topic the address problem and nop method. iam using kali linux 32 bit and have disabled the ASLR but still its not working can anyone give me some direction??

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [buffer overflow protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-smashing_protection#GCC_Stack-Smashing_Protector_.28ProPolice.29) enabled by default? What you are describing sounds like a canary value on your stack.

Comment: no i figured out the code is not working because of nx protection i was trying to run a shellcode in stack thats why

Answer (score 1):

The additional bytes you are seeing on the stack might be alignment bytes introduced by the compiler.